# MQTT to Domoticz with bash

Tags: bash, domoticz

How can i get the value from the file in to Svalue instead of 56.8?

```
mosquitto_pub -h 192.168.0.117 -t domoticz/in -m "$(sudo /home/pi/a.sh)"
```

code for a.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
FILE="/home/pi/testar.log"


echo '{"idx" :179, "svalue" : "56.8" }'
```

I tried to add $file

```
#!/bin/bash
FILE="/home/pi/testar.log"


echo '{"idx" :179, "svalue" : "$file" }'
```

But Domoticz-log dont fix that

```
2017-08-28 08:47:10.300 MQTT: Topic: domoticz/in, Message: {"idx" :179, "svalue" : "$file" }
```

Comment: You have defined file as `FILE` and using it as `file` (variable names mismatch) ? Can you show the contents of the file you are trying to include?

Comment: it just says ex. 53.7

pi@powermeter:~ $ ./temp.sh
53.7


it´s temperture-result from another script

still wrong after correct mismatch
2017-08-28 09:02:47.918 MQTT: Topic: domoticz/in, Message: {"idx" :179, "svalue" : "$FILE" }

Comment: If you are using `bash` shell do file redirection as `'{"idx" :179, "svalue" : "$(< ${file} )" }'`, where `file` is the variable name containing the file

Comment: /home/pi/a.sh: line 5: {"idx" :179, "svalue" : "$(< ${file} )" }: command not found

Comment: If your variable name is `FILE`, use that as `'{"idx" :179, "svalue" : "$(< ${FILE} )" }'`

Comment: #!/bin/bash
FILE="/home/pi/testar.log"
'{"idx" :179, "svalue" : "$(< ${FILE} )" }'

@powermeter:~ $ mosquitto_pub -h 192.168.0.117 -t domoticz/in -m "$(sudo /home/pi/a.sh)"

/home/pi/a.sh: line 3: {"idx" :179, "svalue" : "$(< ${FILE} )" }: command not found

Comment: Which shell are you using `bash` or `sh`?

Comment: Just type this in terminal
mosquitto_pub -h 192.168.0.117 -t domoticz/in -m "$(sudo /home/pi/a.sh)"

Comment: if you are in `sh`, you cannot slurp the file using the `<` operator, in which you need to use `cat`, as `'{"idx" :179, "svalue" : "$(cat FILE)" }'`

Comment: `#!/bin/bash
FILE="/home/pi/testar.log"
echo '{"idx" :179, "svalue" : "$(cat FILE)" }'`

get this on logfile  
`2017-08-28 09:32:04.539 MQTT: Topic: domoticz/in, Message: {"idx" :179, "svalue" : "$(cat FILE)" }`

Comment: It is not clear what you are trying to suggest, did it work or not? if not add more details to the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem is the case.

An if you want the content of file, use "$(< ${file} )